# Working with Lead Conversion with trigger

Tags: leads, lead-conversion

I am trying to write a trigger on lead which gives result as Whenever i update a lead, that should be converted into account, contact and Opportunity. I wrote a trigger, but it is showing following error which shown in pic. and also please 
follow my code.

Trigger:

```
trigger LeadConvert_Trigger on Lead (after update) {

    for(Lead leed : Trigger.New){
        Database.LeadConvert lcon= new Database.LeadConvert();
        lcon.setLeadId(leed.Id);

        LeadStatus convertStatus=[Select id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where isConverted=true];
        lcon.setconvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult result= Database.convertLead(lcon);
    }
}
```

Error

[image]

Comment: I think you should apply a check in your for loop that will check: `if(!leed.isConverted)`

Comment: one more thing you have DML operation in for loop.Which is strictly not suggested.A similar example you can found in [this link](http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2014/07/23/intro-to-apex-auto-converting-leads-in-a-trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

trigger:

```
trigger LeadConvert_Trigger on Lead (after update) {

if(p.firstRun)
    {

  p.firstRun = false;

    for(Lead leed : Trigger.New){
        Database.LeadConvert lcon= new Database.LeadConvert();
        lcon.setLeadId(leed.Id);

        LeadStatus convertStatus=[Select id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where isConverted=true];
        lcon.setconvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult result= Database.convertLead(lcon);
    }

    }
```

class:

```
public class p { 
   public static boolean firstRun = true; 
}
```

Comment: Like other answer and question your code also have DML in loop. `Database.convertLead` counted against the DML limits.

Comment: why 'firstrun' check?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. For some reason, after you convert the lead, salesforce edits it again (probably to set *isConverted* to `true`).

What you need to do is a slightly change on you trigger:

```
Trigger LeadConvert_Trigger on Lead (after update) {
     LeadStatus convertStatus = [
          select MasterLabel
          from LeadStatus
          where IsConverted = true
          limit 1
     ];
     List<Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();

     for (Lead leed: Trigger.new) {
          if (!leed.isConverted) {
               Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();

               lc.setLeadId(leed.Id);
               lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

               leadConverts.add(lc);
          }
     }

     if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
          List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
     }
}
```

Thanks, @Mahmood for providing the link. Also, please check [deadlypenguin's blog](http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2014/07/23/intro-to-apex-auto-converting-leads-in-a-trigger/) for a more thoroughly explanation.

Comment: Using SOQL inside `for` loops is not good practice, and is gonna hit the governor limits. Have that in a list outside of the loop and use the list instead in the loop to set values.

Comment: Oh. True. Great for catching that.

Comment: `Database.convertLead` is a DML, and you dont want that inside your loop as well. This is as dangerous as using SOQL inside loops and prone to hitting governor limits.

Comment: @Mahmood. I looked, but couldn't find a way to mass convert lead. If all conversions has to be made one by one, I don't see another way to do that.

Comment: Hi @Mahmood......!

Comment: Hi @Fernando Gavinho, please follow this link

http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2014/07/23/intro-to-apex-auto-converting-leads-in-a-trigger/

Comment: Hi @Fernando Gavinho, 
can we perform the same trigger with before update on lead?

Comment: Hi @Fernando Gavinho, can you please respond me?

Comment: @KSKumaar I don't think so, because a before update trigger occurs prior to the changes being commited to the database. Wich means you'll lose the changes or that the trigger will fail. 

But give it a try and see what happens xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40885/discussion-between-ks-kumaar-and-fernando-gavinho).

Comment: @KSKumaar/@Fernando: article you shared does it the right way. and you guys should take this as a guideline to write your apex, in this case particularly.

Comment: Starting API v36.0 you should stop using the MasterLabel field on the LeadStatus sobject and use the ApiName field instead.  Sadly SF documentation still tells you to use MasterLabel in example code.  Picklist values had ApiName added which can be different to the Label.